# java- "new" operator in static method

Tags: java, static, new-operator

I know *this* is reference variable which holds the reference for object and static method loads when the class is first accessed by class loader, either to create an instance, or to access a static method or field.
Why its not allowed for `this` but for instance itself? For e.g.

```
Class A{
   public static void main(String... args){
      this.method(); //not allowed
      new A().method(); //allowed, how?
   }
   void method(){
      System.out.println("Class A");
   }
 }
```

Comment: There is no `this` in a static context. The static context exists independently of any class instance. `new A().method()` is creating a new instance, and calling the method upon that.

Comment: "static method loads at compile time at this time state of object in not known" This is a confusing description and suggests to me that you have a poor understanding of what `static` actually means. I suggest you revisit some tutorials. There's plenty of information out there already without us regurgitating it for you.

Comment: `this` references the actual instance; `static` means it is a member (field, method, ....) of the class and not from the/an instance. `main` above is `static`, so it is a method of the class, so there is no instance to be refereed as `this`. `new A()` on the other hand is creating (and returning) an instance, so its methods can be called (accessed). There is nothing being loaded at compile time... as Michael wrote, check what exactly `static` means

Comment: This is where the difference between a class and an object comes into play (there may be 0, 1 or many objects created from one class). When `main` is executed, the class is completely initialized, so at this time (inside `main`) there is no problem in creating an object and using it.

Comment: @Michael I just edited the question according to your feedback and this is what I meant.

Comment: "and static method loads when the class is first accessed by class loader" doesn't sound right. What do you mean by "static method loads"? Do you mean that it is executed when class is loaded? If yes, what makes you think so? Lets say you have class with static method like `class Foo{ public static void saticMethod(){System.out.println("executing staticMethod()");}}` and when you first time use it with `new Foo()` would you see `executing staticMethod()`? No. It looks like you are misunderstanding what `static` is. Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html.

Comment: @Pshemo I know how the static _works_. I am confused about _order_ of initializing of static and instance members. In my knowledge if we have a static members and instance members listed in the same class then order of initilization will be;
static members > instance members

Comment: While you are right about order of initialization, I still don't see how it is related to question asked here. `this` returns reference to instance on which method was invoked, but **`static` method isn't invoked on *instance* of class, but on class itself** so `this` wouldn't be able to return any reference, which is why it doesn't make sense to allow it in static method. But just because `this` can't be used in static method, doesn't mean other ways of obtaining references will also fail. Static method can accept them as parameters, or can create instances on its own and use their references

Comment: Anyway since you are mentioning order of initialization, it looks like you are making some assumption which you are not telling us about, but since provided code doesn't confirmed it you are confused. We don't know what that assumption is, so we can't help you much (without writing full tutorial) unless you express what you think should happen in this code and *what makes you think so*.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.method(); //not allowed
```

You have no instance `this` in static context so you can't invoke method.

```
new A().method(); //allowed, how?
```

You have instance created by `new` operator so that you can invoke a method.

To invoke a method without having a real instance you have to declare it as static. i.e.:

```
static void method(){
  System.out.println(“Class A”);
}
```

this will work when calling just `method()` and via instance:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        method(); //works because method is static
        new A().method(); //still ok, we can call static method using an instance
        this.method(); //not allowed, there is no 'this' in static context
    }

    static void method(){
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables and instance variables follow the initialization order you mention when they are initialized in their declarations. Also static initializer blocks follow that order.

*Methods* (including *constructors*) on the other hand need no initialization at runtime. They are fully defined at compile-time and therefore exist and can be called as soon as the class is loaded, also before the initialization is complete. Therefore there is no problem in your `main` method instantiating the class (calling the default constructor) and calling a method that is declared later, as `method` is declared below `main`.

In addition, the `main` method is also only executed after any static initialization is complete.